# How to edit Android Apps Content through Website ?

Tags: android

Is it possible to edit contents of an android app through web site? For example, contents in a page (videos, texts) & layouts (location, size, colours).

Comment: By working with service, you can handle your android application.

Comment: yes through a REST web service..

Comment: Thanks, that is what I'm seeking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible directly but sounds like you are about to use wrong pattern. The right pattern is a client-server one, where android app is a client and website with REST or any other custom API is a server. Application should request data from server and display it in a way you set up. So you will edit any data on a server and your app will receive changes on request.

Comment: U r wellcome. However, according to SO rules, you has to accept an answer instead of just comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using like `Client` and `Server` approach where your Android app works like Client and your Website is like Server.

You can first download a data and store that data into `SQlite` and whenever you open a application every time app request to Server asking for New data.

You an achieve this using `Sync Date & Time`. Like whenever a website update there data then change `Date & Time` and when your request New data will check `Date & Time`. If `Date & Time` change then your app show `update data message` or `New data available message`. In this way you can achieved.

Comment: Lovely! Thanks for the sync tips.

Based from your explanation, I thought that the app will initiate a request to the server to retrieve content from website every single time the app is opened. 

So, does this mean that SQlite act as a cache in this case?

Comment: As much I'd like to +1 to you, I couldn't as I do not have enough reputation for upvote/downvote itself

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but with any UI field, you can code it programmatically. So for instance, you have a button and want to be able to change the text on it, you can technically do this via a website:

You will need some sort of database management system that will control the content of the app. The app will just have to call the database to get all the data/fields it needs. You will pretty much be making a content management system for your app.

Comment: My superior wanted an app with flexibility of customization from website, so I had no idea how to do it as I've just been learning the Android not long ago. 

Thanks for the info